# How to run a Background Task on iOS application when Internet connection is detected?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, background-process

I'm using a third party library "Reachability.swift"

https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Followed this blog post to identify network event using Notification Center, So the change in network event can be identified dynamically in the foreground

https://blog.pusher.com/handling-internet-connection-reachability-swift/

**My Requirement:-**

I need to run a background service that uses **Alamofire**(Information not needed for alamofire) to push the locally saved SQLite data to the server whenever internet connection status is Active

**Important note:-**
iOS Application should not run in the foreground, everything should happen in the background

Please help me out to understand the topic, Thank in advance!

Comment: Please give me the reason for negative vote, I can improve my question

Comment: Don't use reachability, it is unreliable. When switching connections fast or something the reachability status is almost always incorrect.

Comment: that page gives you information about the possibilities of background execution: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence

Comment: Look at background `UrlSessionConfiguration`s. You can have the system automatically initiate a download when connectivity is available

Answer (score 3):

You should fully read and understand Apple's excellent documentation on background execution: [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

There are only a few application types that are allowed to run permanently in background mode:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Apps of those types must ask for specific permission to run in the background. Declaring a wrong type for your app may lead to app rejection by Apple.